# Making a starter without DME?

Tags: yeast, boil, yeast-starters

Planning to start to use liquid yeasts and will need to do some starters.

It is hard to get hold of DME over here (I can get some hopped LME, though).

I was thinking on doing a starter from grains, do I need to do a full 60 min boil for the starter?

In theory all the sugars the yeast will need are already on the wort when I finish mashing so a short boil (or even pasteurization) just to cripple the competition would be enough? Or do I need to care about DMS, proteins and such for the starter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a mash and short boil will be fine. I sometimes add enough grain to account for an extra gallon or so on a regular-sized all-grain batch, then pressure-can or freeze the resulting wort for starters in the future.

Comment: Keep in mind that the best OG for starter wort is between 1.020 and 1.040.  I aim for 1.030-35.